# Does your hit die include your Constitution modifier for purpose of Wither and Bloom?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing, hit-dice

The *wither and bloom* spell says, in part:

> one creature of your choice in that area can spend and roll one of its unspent Hit Dice and regain a number of hit points equal to the roll plus your spellcasting ability modifier.

Does that bonus include the creature's Constitution modifier?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### No. Adding your Constitution modifier to hit dice is a special feature of short rests.

The *wither and bloom* description tells you that you regain:

> a number of hit points equal to the roll plus your spellcasting ability modifier.

So this is what you regain: the number on the die plus your spellcasting ability modifier. Adding the Constitution modifier is not a general feature of spending hit dice, rather, it is a specific feature of taking a short rest:

> A character can spend one or more Hit Dice at the end of a short rest, up to the character's maximum number of Hit Dice, which is equal to the character's level. **For each Hit Die spent in this way,** the player rolls the die and adds the character's Constitution modifier to it.

Adding the Constitution modifier is only for hit dice *spent in this way*. Features that allow you to spend hit dice in other ways tell you what happens. Since *wither and bloom* does not tell you to add your Constitution modifier, you don’t add it.